# Python - how to make all the buttons aligned per row to look like button wall

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, gtk, pygtk

How to make the buttons per row fixed for large texts so that it looks like the expected output almost where all the buttons are aligned like wall.

Not working:

[image]

Expected output:

[image]

Code: not working to align

```
import gobject, gtk
gobject.threads_init()

class rightclick(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
    self.window.modify_bg(gtk.STATE_NORMAL, gtk.gdk.Color(0, 0, 0))
    self.window.set_size_request(630, 480)
    self.window.set_border_width(1)
    self.window.set_title("PIPTPT")
    self.window.move(0,720 /3 - 200 )
    self.window.set_name("main window")
    self.window.connect("delete-event", gtk.main_quit)
    self.vbox = gtk.VBox()
    self.vbox.set_border_width(0)
    self.vbox.pack_start(self.create_bbox(True, "",5, gtk.BUTTONBOX_START), True, True, 0)
    self.window.add(self.vbox)

  def create_bbox(self, horizontal, title, spacing, layout):
      frame = gtk.Frame(title)
      frame.set_label_align( 0, 0)
      frame.set_shadow_type( gtk.SHADOW_NONE)
      frame.set_border_width(2)
      if horizontal:
          bbox = gtk.HButtonBox()
      else:
          bbox = gtk.VButtonBox()

      bbox.set_border_width(0)
      frame.add(bbox)
      bbox.set_layout(layout)
      bbox.set_spacing(0)
      button_height= 22
      for x in range(0, 35):
        button = gtk.Button()
        button.props.relief = gtk.RELIEF_NONE
        label = gtk.Label()
        label.set_markup('<span color="#bbbbbb"><small>Long Long Long</small></span>');
        button.add(label)
        button.set_size_request(48, button_height)
        button.connect("clicked" , self.button_quit , None)
        bbox.add(button)

      return frame

  def run(self):
    self.window.show_all()
    self.window.set_keep_above(True)
    if(self.window.get_window().get_state() == gtk.gdk.WINDOW_STATE_MAXIMIZED):
      self.window.unmaximize()
    gtk.main()

  def button_quit(self, widget, event):
    gtk.main_quit()

if __name__=='__main__':
    s=rightclick()
    s.run()
gobject.MainLoop.run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - this example is what i was looking for, it works.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import gtk

class PyApp(gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        super(PyApp, self).__init__()

        self.set_title("Calculator")
        self.set_size_request(250, 230)
        self.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER)

        vbox = gtk.VBox(False, 2)
        table = gtk.Table(5, 4, True)

        table.attach(gtk.Button("Cls"), 0, 1, 0, 1)
        table.attach(gtk.Button("Bck"), 1, 2, 0, 1)
        table.attach(gtk.Label(), 2, 3, 0, 1)
        table.attach(gtk.Button("Close"), 3, 4, 0, 1)

        table.attach(gtk.Button("7"), 0, 1, 1, 2)
        table.attach(gtk.Button("8"), 1, 2, 1, 2)
        table.attach(gtk.Button("9"), 2, 3, 1, 2)
        table.attach(gtk.Button("/"), 3, 4, 1, 2)

        table.attach(gtk.Button("4"), 0, 1, 2, 3)
        table.attach(gtk.Button("5"), 1, 2, 2, 3)
        table.attach(gtk.Button("6"), 2, 3, 2, 3)
        table.attach(gtk.Button("*"), 3, 4, 2, 3)

        table.attach(gtk.Button("1"), 0, 1, 3, 4)
        table.attach(gtk.Button("2"), 1, 2, 3, 4)
        table.attach(gtk.Button("3"), 2, 3, 3, 4)
        table.attach(gtk.Button("-"), 3, 4, 3, 4)

        table.attach(gtk.Button("0"), 0, 1, 4, 5)
        table.attach(gtk.Button("."), 1, 2, 4, 5)
        table.attach(gtk.Button("="), 2, 3, 4, 5)
        table.attach(gtk.Button("+"), 3, 4, 4, 5)

        #vbox.pack_start(gtk.Entry(), False, False, 0)
        vbox.pack_end(table, True, True, 0)

        self.add(vbox)

        self.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)
        self.show_all()


PyApp()
gtk.main()
```